# How can I make logrotate work for custom apache log location?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I changed `/etc/apache2/envars` like this.

```
#export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/lv1/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
```

And it seems to work. Logs appended in the new directory.

And I changed `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` like this.

```
/lv1/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
```

And it seems not to work. Logs keep being appended to the same `access.log`.

How can I make logroate to work for this?

Comment: Have you tried running `logrotate --debug` manually? This could be anything from missing access rights to a syntax error in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the apache [logging docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#rotation) you need to restart the server when the logs are rotated for it to open the new file.

So you can put a postrotate section in with

```
postrotate
        /path/to/apachectl graceful
```